# Displaying grades in a graph

Tags: c++, paragraph

Im supposed to display grades in a graph that shows how many grades are in each interval 0-10, 10-20, 20-30 etc. By putting a `*` for each grade in the interval. My only problem is that when the array `grade[]` has 1, 2, 3 or 5 slots it puts an extra `*` in the 0-10 interval. It works with every other ammount of slots.

```
void sort_grades(int grades[],int students) 

    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << " THE GRADES GRAPH"<< endl;
    cout << "=============================="<<endl;

    const int max_grade = 100;
    const int interval=10;

    for (int j = 0; j < max_grade; j+=10)
    {
        cout << j << " - " << (j+interval) << " : ";

        for (int k = 0; k <= students; k++)
        {
            if (j==90 && grades[k] ==(j+interval)  )
            {
                cout<< "*";
            }
            else if (grades[k] < (j+interval) && grades[k] >= j)
            {
                cout<< "*";
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to run your code in a debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that `students` is the size of the array `grades[]`.

In this case, you access too many elements in the following loop:

```
for (int k = 0; k <= students; k++)
```

Instead the line should read:

```
for (int k = 0; k < students; k++)
```

This problem does *not* only occur for the cases where `grade[]` has a size of 1, 2, 3 or 5. You only *see* the problem for that sizes, because the output depends on the content of the array.